# How to reverse ant design slider? fix the max value

Tags: reactjs, slider, antd, rangeslider

How to reverse ant design slider? fix the max value. Only changing min value.
[having max value fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5o8n4.png)

Comment: Both images are the same

Comment: What have you done? consider take look how to ask correctly a question SO https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask